# How to access column via index when using iterrows()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to know how I can access columns using index rather than name when using `iterrows` to traverse DataFrames.

This code is most I could find:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print row['Date']
```

This is another approach I took to traverse, but it seems very slow:

```
for i in df.index:
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):       
                    df.ix[i,j] = 0
```

Comment: If you want to convert your strings to numbers just call `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: I want to do it based on some conditions

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ix` to access by index:

```
In [67]: df
Out[67]:
       A  B
0  test1  1
1  test2  4
2  test3  1
3  test4  2

In [68]: df.ix[:,1]
Out[68]:
0    1
1    4
2    1
3    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Updating your code with first column:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row.ix[0]
```

Comment: I tried that but it's taking too much time, I'm using a data-set of over 45000 rows

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? by explaining your problem instead of a technical question, we may help better!

Comment: I have a data set which has multiple columns, strings and integers
I want to map all strings to integers, so I want to iterate over rows and columns and replace all strings with integer values
The way I do this is
For example there is a 'marital status' column, its field can have 'single,married,divorced' status, so if a field contains single, I would map it to 0

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed enter, please read my comment again, just updated.

Comment: I added the updated for loop. Your problem formulation is completely different from the original question. You should use masking to replace desired value.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rG1VWYKj
I wrote this code but it seems to hang my Jupyter Notebook, it just shows "In [*]" and no other response. Is something wrong with this code?

Comment: The problem with masking is that there are too many unique values and columns and I'd have to hard code all of them, this is why I want to use a loop to replace values.

Comment: please close the question on ask another one on a different topic, it breaks SO rules to overwhelm a single thread with different questions. By the way do not provide a link but put a minimal example in your question ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90966/discussion-between-xoul-and-colonel-beauvel).

Comment: No. Beware I can't access this from my firewall.

Comment: ix is deprecated since pandas 0.23 +

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Iterate for `i to number of columns` and use `i` as index to access columns:

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)):  
    for index, row in df.iterrows():    
        print row.ix[i]
```